# Can not I properly configure expires headers for apache

Tags: http-headers, apache-2.4, apache-2.2

I am trying to configure caching for static js/css/img on `apache2` (I am using `ubuntu`). I do not want to use `.htaccess` [due to this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/21058/30526).

So I tried the following:

1. enabled `modexpires`
2. modified `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` by adding the following

   `ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 1 months"
   ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 months"
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"`

After restarting apache I found that my expires headers are 1 month after current day, but Chrome shows that I am still reading the file and do use the cache.

Because I am using amazon ec2, I tried to remove eTag with `FileEtag None`. But still with no success. Here is a screenshot of my Request/Response headers.

[image]

As far as I understood gzip is enabled and expires headers are correct. Also my cache is enabled in Chrome dev tools. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?